# How to call functions in python files that are not in the working directory?

Tags: python

Say now my working folder is `.` and my supporting python files are in `./supporting_files/`, I want to call a function `func` in the `a.py` file under `./supporting_files/`, what should I do? I tried calling `from supporting_files.a import func` and that does not work. How am I suppose to do that without changing the actual working directory?

Comment: Do you have the `__init__.py` in `supporting_files` directory? What's your python version?

Comment: No I don't have one. It's python 2.7

Comment: works for me, cannot reproduce. edit: works in python3 but not in 2.7

Comment: You need to put an empty `__init__.py` in your directory in order to be interpreted as a module, by python.

Comment: [Python 2 tutorial chapter 6 on modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `__init__.py` file (it can be empty) to the `supporting_files` directory, and python will treat it as a package available for imports. More details are available in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways you can do that I'm aware of.

## Wrong way

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./supporting_files')    
from a import func
func()
```

## Right way

```
$ touch supporting_files/__init__.py
```

Then

```
import supporting_files.a as a

a.func()
```

Comment: I mean it works, but works in kind of the same way that a Rube Goldberg machine works. It's fine for entertainment/education but you wouldn't ever want to drive your space program that way.

Comment: Thanks I think I got it